# Very simple AVG() aggregation query on MySQL server takes ridiculously long time

Tags: mysql, aggregation

I am using MySQL server via Amazon could service, with default settings. The table involved `mytable` is of `InnoDB` type and has about 1 billion rows.
The query is:

```
select count(*), avg(`01`) from mytable where `date` = "2017-11-01";
```

Which takes almost 10 min to execute. I have an index on `date`. The `EXPLAIN` of this query is:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+---------+-------+
| id | select_type | table         | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref   | rows    | Extra |
+----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+---------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable       | ref  | date          | date | 3       | const | 1411576 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+---------+-------+
```

The indexes from this table are:

```
+---------------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table         | Non_unique | Key_name  | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| mytable       |          0 | PRIMARY   |            1 | ESI         | A         |    60398679 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| mytable       |          0 | PRIMARY   |            2 | date        | A         |  1026777555 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| mytable       |          1 | lse_cd    |            1 | lse_cd      | A         |     1919210 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| mytable       |          1 | zone      |            1 | zone        | A         |      732366 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| mytable       |          1 | date      |            1 | date        | A         |    85564796 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| mytable       |          1 | ESI_index |            1 | ESI         | A         |     6937686 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+---------------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

If I remove `AVG()`:

```
select count(*) from mytable where `date` = "2017-11-01";
```

It only takes 0.15 sec to return the count. The count of this specific query is 692792; The counts are similar for other `date`s.

I don't have an index over `01`. Is it an issue? Why `AVG()` takes so long to compute? There must be something I didn't do properly.

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: For performance questions, please always add your indexes (and an explain plan, although it is not required here). Here it might also be relevant if you use MyISAM or InnoDB. Did you try to repeat your queries? Caching might be involved here (so the times are not directly comparable). Also: how many rows do you have for each `date`? I assume some 100k or more? I also assume you have an index on `date` (which can speed up your `count(*)`), but it isn't the first part of your primary key? Try a covering index `mytable(date, 01)`, it should speed up your query (under those assumptions).

Comment: Thank you, I edited the question accordingly. I think I have two indexes on `date`, as shown in the edited question. And I did try to repeat my queries.

Comment: About "covering index": I have columns from `01` to `24` and I need to calculate `AVG()` for all of them. Is it still viable to index all of them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To count the number of rows with a specific date, MySQL has to locate that value in the index (which is pretty fast, after all that is what indexes are made for) and then read the subsequent entries *of the index* until it finds the next date. Depending on the datatype of `esi`, this will sum up to reading some MB of data to count your 700k rows. Reading some MB does not take much time (and that data might even already be cached in the buffer pool, depending on how often you use the index).

To calculate the average for a column that is not included in the index, MySQL will, again, use the index to find all rows for that date (the same as before). But additionally, for every row it finds, it has to read the actual table data for that row, which means to use the primary key to locate the row, read some bytes, and repeat this 700k times. This ["random access"](https://www.percona.com/blog/2008/04/28/the-mysql-optimizer-the-os-cache-and-sequential-versus-random-io/) is *a lot* slower than the sequential read in the first case. (This gets worse by the problem that "some bytes" is the [`innodb_page_size`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_page_size) (16KB by default), so you may have to read up to 700k * 16KB = 11GB, compared to "some MB" for `count(*)`; and depending on your memory configuration, some of this data might not be cached and has to be read from disk.)

A solution to this is to include all used columns in the index (a "covering index"), e.g. create an index on `date, 01`. Then MySQL does not need to access the table itself, and can proceed, similar to the first method, by just reading the index. The size of the index will increase a bit, so MySQL will need to read "some more MB" (and perform the `avg`-operation), but it should still be a matter of seconds.

In the comments, you mentioned that you need to calculate the average over 24 columns. If you want to calculate the `avg` for several columns at the same time, you would need a covering index on all of them, e.g. `date, 01, 02, ..., 24` to prevent table access. Be aware that an index that contains all columns requires as much storage space as the table itself (and it will take a long time to create such an index), so it might depend on how important this query is if it is worth those resources.

To avoid the [MySQL-limit of 16 columns per index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html), you could split it into two indexes (and two queries). Create e.g. the indexes `date, 01, .., 12` and `date, 13, .., 24`, then use

```
select * from (select `date`, avg(`01`), ..., avg(`12`) 
               from mytable where `date` = ...) as part1
cross join    (select avg(`13`), ..., avg(`24`) 
               from mytable where `date` = ...) as part2;
```

Make sure to document this well, as there is no obvious reason to write the query this way, but it might be worth it.

If you only ever average over a single column, you could add 24 seperate indexes (on `date, 01`, `date, 02`, ...), although in total, they will require even more space, but might be a little bit faster (as they are smaller individually). But the buffer pool might still favour the full index, depending on factors like usage patterns and memory configuration, so you may have to test it.

Since `date` is part of your primary key, you could also consider changing the primary key to `date, esi`. If you find the dates by the primary key, you would not need an additional step to access the table data (as you already access the table), so the behaviour would be similar to the covering index. But this is a significant change to your table and can affect all other queries (that e.g. use `esi` to locate rows), so it has to be considered carefully.

As you mentioned, another option would be to build a summary table where you store precalculated values, especially if you do not add or modify rows for past dates (or can keep them up-to-date with a trigger).

Comment: Thank you! I learned a lot and now I understand why it is slow. I cannot change the order of the primary key to `date, esi`, since in the question I simplified the query. I indeed need `esi` first to target a group of `esi`s. I will try to add a covering index and report the performance here.

Comment: It turns out I cannot add a covering index for all columns. I got an error "Too many key parts specified; max 16 parts allowed". I guess I have to look for alternative methods. Since all I care about is the average value, I'm thinking to create another table with just the averaged values. This will need one or two days but after that, all queries on the smaller table would be fast.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I forgot about that limitation; I added a solution to this (splitting the index), but a summary table would probably be a proper solution too (and saves significant resources), if you can keep it up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

For MyISAM tables, COUNT(*) is optimized to return very quickly if the SELECT retrieves from one table, no other columns are retrieved, and there is no WHERE clause.

For example:

> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM student;

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count

If you add AVG() or something else, you lose this optimization

Comment: "and there is no WHERE clause." does not apply here.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! My table uses InnoDB engine. Is what you said still true for InnoDB?

Comment: @ChunjiWang 
To process a SELECT COUNT(*) statement, InnoDB scans an index of the table, which takes some time if the index is not entirely in the buffer pool. For a faster count, you can create a counter table and let your application update it according to the inserts and deletes it does. However, this method may not scale well in situations where thousands of concurrent transactions are initiating updates to the same counter table. If an approximate row count is sufficient, SHOW TABLE STATUS can be used.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-restrictions.html