# MySQL RDS performance of aggregation functions

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, performance, rds, amazon-aurora

We have a query that performs some aggregation on one column.
The filtering of the data seems to be pretty fast, but the aggregation seems to take too much time.

This query returns ~ 1.5 million rows. It runs for 0.6 seconds (if we want to return the data to the client it takes ~ 2 minutes - the way we tested this is by using the [pymysql](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#) python library. We used an unbuffered cursor, so we can distinguish between query run time and fetch time):

```
SELECT *
FROM t_data t1
      WHERE (t1.to_date = '2019-03-20')
       AND (t1.period = 30)
       AND (label IN ('aa','bb') )
       AND ( id IN (
                SELECT id
                FROM t_location_data
                WHERE (to_date = '2019-03-20') AND (period = 30)
                  AND ( country = 'Narniya'  ) ) )
```

But if we run this query:

```
SELECT  MAX(val) val_max,
        AVG(val) val_avg,
        MIN(val) val_min
FROM t_data t1
      WHERE (t1.to_date = '2019-03-20')
       AND (t1.period = 30)
       AND (label IN ('aa','bb') )
       AND ( id IN (
                SELECT id
                FROM t_location_data
                WHERE (to_date = '2019-03-20') AND (period = 30)
                  AND ( country = 'Narniya'  ) ) )
```

We see that the time to run the query takes 40 seconds and the time to fetch the results in this case is obviously less than a second..

Any help with this terrible performance of the aggregation functions over RDS Aurora? Why calculating Max Min and Avergae on 1.5 million lines takes so long (When comparing to Python on those same numbers, the calculation takes less than 1 second..)

NOTE: We added random number to each select to make sure we do not get cached values.

We use Aurora RDS:
*1 instance of db.r5.large (2 vCPU + 16 GB RAM)
MySQL Engine version: 5.6.10a*

Create table:

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `t_data` (
  `id` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `val2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `val3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `val` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `val4` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tags` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `val7` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `label` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `val5` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `val6` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `period` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `to_date` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_line_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`data_line_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_data` (`to_date`,`period`,`id`),
  KEY `index1` (`to_date`,`period`,`id`),
  KEY `index3` (`to_date`,`period`,`label`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=218620560 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Create Table: CREATE TABLE `t_location_data` (
  `id` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `val8` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `val9` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `period` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `to_date` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `location_line_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`location_line_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_location_data` (`to_date`,`period`,`id`,`latitude`,`longitude`),
  KEY `index1` (`to_date`,`period`,`id`,`country`),
  KEY `index2` (`country`,`state`,`city`),
  KEY `index3` (`to_date`,`period`,`country`,`state`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=315944737 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Parameters:

```
@@innodb_buffer_pool_size/1024/1024/1024:  7.7900
@@innodb_buffer_pool_instances:            8
```

**UPDATE:**
Adding the `val` index (like suggest by @rick-james) did improve the query dramatically (took ~2 seconds) **only if I delete** the `AND ( id IN (SELECT id FROM t_location_data..` condition. If I leave it, the query runs for about ~25 seconds.. better than before but still not good..

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, are you comparing 0.6s of above query with 40s of the one below? If such is the case then perhaps having an index on `val` could help.

Comment: Any `TEXT` columns?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: I found this very usefull to understand: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49397333/very-simple-avg-aggregation-query-on-mysql-server-takes-ridiculously-long-time

Comment: "we can distinguish between query run time and fetch time" -- However one way (buffered vs unbuffered) is significantly faster than the other.

Answer (score 1):

Indexes needed:

```
t_data:  INDEX(period, to_date, label, val)
t_data:  INDEX(period, label, to_date, val)
t_location_data:  INDEX(period, country, to_date, id)
```

Also, change from the slow `IN ( SELECT ... )` to a `JOIN`:

```
FROM t_data AS d
JOIN t_location_data AS ld USING(id)
WHERE ...
```

Better yet, since the tables are 1:1 (is that correct?), combine the tables so as to eliminate the `JOIN`.  If `id` is not the `PRIMARY KEY` in each table, you *really* need to provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and should change the name(s).

Comment: The tables are not 1:1, the t_location_data has many lines per id.. so using join will give more lines and this is not good.. The real names in the our project are different, I just renamed here for simplicity..

Comment: Regarding the indexes, I'll try and see if gives better performance.. but why do I need two indexes on the t_data?

Comment: So, adding the index on val did some performance improvements.. but still not like expected (1-2 seconds).. The "problem" is that I need to calc MAX, MIN, AVG on another 10 columns, so I'll need to add all of them to index.. so I'm wondering what is the purpose of the table storage if all fields I "really" need to read are coming from the index..

Comment: @ChananelP - Which 10 columns?  It makes a big difference as to whether all 10 are in one table  (and which table) versus both tables.  Also, your comment has opened up another can of worms -- `AVG` over one table will give one result; `AVG` over the `JOIN` of two tables may give a _different_ value.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't exact, I meant 7 columns (val, val2..val7) from the `t_data` table. The `t_location_data` is only here for filtering and no need to calculate aggregations on its values.. (That's why I do NOT join the tables..)

Comment: Does `JOIN` give you the right answer?  If not, show us the `JOIN`.